# Google analytics page tracking is not working properly in angularjs app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-analytics

My project is on angularjs, which is both for mobile app and desktop site.
I have saved analytics.js on my local and used it in GA tracking code.
My tracking code is in index.html file:

```
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','js/analytics.js','ga');
  ga('create', 'UA-57325467-1', 'auto');
  ga('set', 'checkStorageTask', null);
  ga('set', 'checkProtocolTask', null);
  ga('send', 'pageview');
```

In cotroller , I have used following code for page tracking:

```
ga('send', 'pageview', $location.url());
```

It's showing 1 user online(that's me).It's tracking events on all pages.But problem is with pageview.
When i am visiting different pages of my application and checking in goolge analytics real time->overview
I am seeing "/" there ,whereas when I am coming back to the pages then page tracking is working fine(but not always).
Basically it's not tracking pages all the time.Sometimes it works and sometimes I see only "/".

Comment: Did you send a new `pageview` when switching page?

Comment: Yes, i am sending pageview for every page switch

Answer (score 1):

For using google analytics in angular projects I recommend using the [angular module](https://github.com/revolunet/angular-google-analytics).

It does what you want automatically.

I know it is not an direct answer to your question, but I thought instead of debugging yourself you might use a unit tested library.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that have enabled the Real time Analytics. Follow the steps in this reference document to enable Real time analytics

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1638635?hl=en

Other Reasons you are data may not be shown are

Data collection limit:

If a property sends more hits per month to Analytics than allowed by the Analytics Terms of Service, 
there is no assurance that the excess hits will be processed. If the property's hit volume exceeds this limit, 
a warning may be displayed in the user interface and you may be prevented from accessing reports.

Data processing latency:

Processing latency is 24-48 hours. Standard accounts that send more than 200,000 sessions per day to Analytics will result in the reports being refreshed only once a day. 
This can delay updates to reports and metrics for up to two days.
To restore intra-day processing, reduce the number of sessions your account sends to < 200,000 per day.

Reference:

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1070983?hl=en